SF story where classical element theory is correct; space battle to reduce elemental earth fortress
Probably back in the ’70s or ’80s, I read a story that I’d like to re-locate. I don’t remember all the details, and what I do remember is one small section of it, but…
Our complex science of atoms and compounds with protons, neutrons, electrons, etc., had been proven wrong, and classical element theory (four elements: earth, air, fire, water; everything is just a mixture of the four in various proportions) was actually correct. In the scene I remember, there was a space battle going on; the viewpoint character was talking to another character, who may have been non-human, about the battle. The non-human was an expert in working with adamantium (essentially, high-purity elemental earth), and the battle was to obtain payment from a customer who had ordered (and had been delivered) an adamantium fortress. Since it was proving to be un-reduceable (as designed), the non-human was resolving never to build an entire construct of adamantium for anyone ever again.

You probably don't mean Richard Garfinkle's novel on that theme (Celestial Matters) from 1996, but I thought I'd mention it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_Matters

@Andrew - Nope, definitely not that, nor the Farmer story ("Sail On! Sail On!") that it links to.

Star Winds by Barrington J. Bailey.

The alien is Flammarion and he built the adamant fortress (called an Aegis) for the Duke of Koss:

"This is Flammarion," Matello said to Rachad, "a master builder from the other side of the galaxy. He it was who built the duke’s Aegis, long ago, and he and I are now united in a common purpose—somehow to break into that aegis. It is an ambition not altogether unique to us, for the duke has many enemies."

Flammarion explains:

Flammarion paused again and went surging through the powder. "Thinking to employ my talents in foreign parts of the galaxy, I traveled to that region where humans dwell. Here I was commissioned by the Duke of Koss to build an aegis for him. I labored mightily, constructing, I believe, the best example of my skills so far. Finally the work was finished, the duke took up residence, and after a decent interval to allow inspection, I presented myself before the gate to collect my fee: two tons of heavenly water, a rare commodity much prized by my kind."
The voice of the alien became burdened with dole. "His answer was direct and most unkind. 'If the Aegis is truly invulnerable as claimed by you and specified by contract, you have no means by which to enter and extract payment. You cannot hurt me; here I shall remain forever. Begone!' Oh, cruel injustice! Since then I have remained nearby, trying by this stratagem and that to force payment from my client."

Adamant is described as:

"Oh, I too can make adamant, in small quantities," Amschel chuckled. "Still, I am glad to see that you have a lively mind. Let me explain adamant to you. It is simply elemental earth, purged of all trace of other elements. Being so purged, and pure, it is impervious to all assaults—impervious even to the alkahest."


Thank you. This is definitely it. And somehow I'm not surprised that it's BJB...
